# Convective derivative vs Divergence of velocity

Tags: vectors, partial-derivative, fluid-dynamics, divergence-operator

What is the physical significance or difference between Convective derivative : $\vec{v} \cdot \nabla $ and the Divergence of velocity $\nabla \cdot \vec{v}$?

I have understood the convective derivative as the measure of change of a function along the direction of velocity. i.e. simply like the dot product. For example, the first component $u \frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{x}}$ of the convective derivative applied to density. I think of i as the **projection of the change of density along x** on the **x-component of velocity**. Is it right to think so? If there is a better reasoning please let me know.

Now coming to the divergence of velocity, how is this different from the convective derivative? I know that the dot product is commutative. Then how does this have a different meaning? i.e. Why does it take the velocity components into the derivative?

Does the Del operator have a different meaning if the **order of the dot product is changed**?

I come from a Mechanical engineering background with an interest in fluid dynamics, hence my interest in understanding the physical meanings. I also appreciate mathematical explanations. All perspectives are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convective derivative, $\vec{v} \cdot \nabla$, is a differential operator; it acts on whatever you write to its right, to produce
$$
(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) f
= \vec{v} \cdot (\nabla f)
= v_1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}
+ v_2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}
+ v_3 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}
.
$$
But the divergence of the velocity, $\nabla \cdot \vec{v}$, is just a scalar field (i.e., a real-valued function):
$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{v}
= \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1}
+ \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_2}
+ \frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_3}
.
$$
So they are completely different things. The point is that the operator $\nabla$ acts on what stands immediately to the right of it, so it makes a big difference whether you write the vector field $\vec{v}$ before or after the $\nabla$.

Comment: I have another query now. In the convective derivative, the unit vectors of velocity vector and of the divergence operator multiply each other and turn to 1. 
Is it the same case with the divergence of velocity? In that case, do both things happen together, i.e. the divergence operator acts on the velocity and also takes the dot product?

Comment: To be more clear, since in the convective derivative the vector dot poduct is already taken, that function as you said is just a differential operator, so when it act on a vector valued function where do the unit vectors of those function go? 
Or should I infer that the output of it is a vector?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean, but $\nabla \cdot \vec{v}$ is basically just a symbolic notation for the expression I wrote in my answer, don't overthink it. And the convective derivative simply acts component-wise on a vector-valued function.